# Array[Byte] Spark RDD to String Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I'm using the Cloudera's SparkOnHBase module in order to get data from HBase.

I get a RDD in this way:

```
var getRdd = hbaseContext.hbaseRDD("kbdp:detalle_feedback", scan)
```

Based on that, what I get is an object of type

```
RDD[(Array[Byte], List[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])])]
```

which corresponds to row key and a list of values. All of them represented by a byte array.

If I save the getRDD to a file, what I see is:

```
([B@f7e2590,[([B@22d418e2,[B@12adaf4b,[B@48cf6e81), ([B@2a5ffc7f,[B@3ba0b95,[B@2b4e651c), ([B@27d0277a,[B@52cfcf01,[B@491f7520), ([B@3042ad61,[B@6984d407,[B@f7c4db0), ([B@29d065c1,[B@30c87759,[B@39138d14), ([B@32933952,[B@5f98506e,[B@8c896ca), ([B@2923ac47,[B@65037e6a,[B@486094f5), ([B@3cd385f2,[B@62fef210,[B@4fc62b36), ([B@5b3f0f24,[B@8fb3349,[B@23e4023a), ([B@4e4e403e,[B@735bce9b,[B@10595d48), ([B@5afb2a5a,[B@1f99a960,[B@213eedd5), ([B@2a704c00,[B@328da9c4,[B@72849cc9), ([B@60518adb,[B@9736144,[B@75f6bc34)])
```

for each record (rowKey and the columns)

But what I need is to get the String representation of all and each of the keys and values. Or at least the values. In order to save it to a file and see something like

```
key1,(value1,value2...)
```

or something like

```
key1,value1,value2...
```

I'm completely new on spark and scala and it's being quite hard to get something.

Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First lets create some sample data:

```
scala> val d = List( ("ab" -> List(("qw", "er", "ty")) ), ("cd" -> List(("ac", "bn", "afad")) ) )
d: List[(String, List[(String, String, String)])] = List((ab,List((qw,er,ty))), (cd,List((ac,bn,afad))))
```

This is how the data is:

```
scala> d foreach println
(ab,List((qw,er,ty)))
(cd,List((ac,bn,afad)))
```

Convert it to `Array[Byte]` format

```
scala> val arrData = d.map { case (k,v) => k.getBytes() -> v.map { case (a,b,c) => (a.getBytes(), b.getBytes(), c.getBytes()) } }

arrData: List[(Array[Byte], List[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])])] = List((Array(97, 98),List((Array(113, 119),Array(101, 114),Array(116, 121)))), (Array(99, 100),List((Array(97, 99),Array(98, 110),Array(97, 102, 97, 100)))))
```

Create an RDD out of this data

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(arrData)
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Array[Byte], List[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:25
```

Create a conversion function from `Array[Byte]` to `String`:

```
scala> def b2s(a: Array[Byte]): String = new String(a)
b2s: (a: Array[Byte])String
```

Perform our final conversion:

```
scala> val rdd2 = rdd1.map { case (k,v) => b2s(k) -> v.map{ case (a,b,c) => (b2s(a), b2s(b), b2s(c)) } }
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, String, String)])] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:29

scala> rdd2.collect()
res2: Array[(String, List[(String, String, String)])] = Array((ab,List((qw,er,ty))), (cd,List((ac,bn,afad))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much tuxdna. This is exactly what I needed. Very good explained with all the steps.  It seems to be pretty easy now that you wrote the solution   :)

Comment: Is there any other way round? Converting RDD to ByteArray

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN By default Spark is using default serializer ( which is Java de/serializer ). You could also use Kryo serializer to avoid this manual transformation - For more details https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790946/how-to-register-byte-using-kryo-serialization-for-spark should help.

Comment: can you help solve this problem ? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089412/converting-array-of-strings-in-spark-to-byte-array-and-retrieving-it-back-using]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about HBase but if those `Array[Byte]`s are Unicode strings, something like this should work:

```
rdd: RDD[(Array[Byte], List[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte], Array[Byte])])] = *whatever*
rdd.map(k, l => 
  (new String(k),
  l.map(a => 
    a.map(elem =>
      new String(elem)
    )
  ))
)
```

Sorry for bad styling and whatnot, I am not even sure it will work.

Comment: thank you very much mehmetminanc. It's not exactly working in that way but it gave me a good idea to face the problem.

Comment: @tuxdna explained very neatly, but I don't get how one works and the other does not. Both seem semantically the same.

Comment: more than probably mehmetminanc. It's because of my unexperience that I understood better in the other way.

Comment: I was not interested in the best answer and tuxdna has the better answer. I was just remarking that they are the same.